# Raising exception from within except clause

Tags: python, exception

I'm wondering if we can do something like the following:
We catch socket error and if the message is different than some value,
 raise the exception forward to be caught on the next general except clause below?

```
try:
    some logic to connect to a server..   

except socket.error as se:
    if se.messsage != '123':
       raise Exception(se.message)
except exception as ex:
    log.error('write something')
```

Comment: No, you can't. But you can have a `try...except` nested in another `try...except`.

Comment: I thought of that but is looks and feel not good

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you need a set of try-catch blocks. Once, an exception has been caught, re-throwing the exception results in it being caught at the outer level. Try if else inside the blocks or simply nest try-except block in another one like this:

```
try:
    try:
        #...
    except:
        raise
except:
    pass
```

Comment: I'd call that "nested try-except blocks" and write the example to more closely match the question, but otherwise good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply re-raise the exception with `raise` without arguments:

```
try:
    # some code
except:
    if condition:
        raise
```